# Finding Twin Primes with Constructor

Tags: java, constructor, primes

Just for fun, i wanted to see whether i could employ a code to display twin primes as practice for learning Constructors. I though i had used a good logic but for some reason i couldnt make it work.

This program is to print all twin primes(primes with 1 gap between them) till a given number as input by the user.

```
package X;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class TwinPrimeWithConstructor {
    int limit;

    public void Twin() {
        limit = 0;
    }

    public static void input() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Limit");
        int limit = input.nextInt();
    }

    public void display() {
        for (int k = 1; k <= (limit - 2); k++) {
            int a = prime(k);
            int b = prime(k + 2);
            if (a == 1 && b == 1) {
                System.out.println(k + "," + k + 2);
            }
        }
    }

    public int prime(int n) {
        int c = 0;
        int d = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                c = c + 1;
            }
        }
        if (c == 2) {
            d = 1;
            return d;
        } else {
            return d;
        }
    }

    void main() {
        TwinPrimeWithConstructor ob = new TwinPrimeWithConstructor();
        ob.input();
        ob.display();
    }
}
```

This program manages to correctly detect primes and asks for input,but does not give any output. Can someone make it clear to me? I'm still learning java so any help would be appreciated.
Also since im new, if you find any bad habits in my code, please feel free to tell me so i can become a better programmer.

Comment: first of all formatting but I see that @deHaar has updated It

Comment: @deHaar you shouldn't have renamed the variable names even if they don't follow Java naming conventions

Comment: @AndrewTobilko ok, thanks... I will take that into account in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not getting any output because `this.limit` is always `0`:

```
int limit = Input.nextInt();
```

You should assign the input to your instance field rather than to a new local variable. To do this, the `input` method must not be `static`:

```
public void input() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Limit");
    limit = input.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply but can u elaborate a bit? I dont get why the "this "keyword has to be used here. Also how does static make a difference?

Comment: @JamesAdams you assign the input to a local variable which will vanish after the method finishes execution.

Comment: @JamesAdams your field is an instance field (related to an instance); static methods (related to a class) can't refer to instance members

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I did what u said and my run was successful. However, i found that changing int limit to just limit made the difference. Can someone explain to me why this is so?

Comment: @JamesAdams `int limit` is a declaration of a local variable which doesn't relate to the `limit` field. the `display` method refers to the field, it can't know about local changes in other methods